# plot optimized curve Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

Having 2 vectors vec_x and vec_y, i perform a fitting with a non-linear least squares like this :

```
%%myfunction.m
function F = myfun(x,vec_x)
    F = 10*(erfc((x(1)+x(2)*vec_x)/sqrt(2))/2);  
end
%%console 
options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
x = lsqcurvefit(@myfun, [0 1], vec_x, vec_y,[],[],options); %here i obtain x(1) and x(2).
```

When i want to plot the fitting curve with the associated points(vec_x .vs vec_y), i perform it like this :

```
y_fit=10*erfc((x(1)+x(2)*vec_x)/sqrt(2))/2
plot(vec_x,y_fit)
```

The problem is that i have a weird curve not similar to the one i have automatically when i'm using the "Curv-fit App" tool of Matlab (i use the same custom function and vectors as the console).

In the Curve-fitting GUI, i got this : see the image below
[snapshot-curveFitting-GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19wix.png)

How can i have the right plot so i can more mange the plot ?

Comment: Does the missing factor of 10 in `y_fit` affect the plot?

Comment: your function requires two argumnets (x, fmpd...), don't you need to pass the second argument as part of the optimization (pass extra parameters) or freeze the fmpd_dinosaur parameter in myfun a priori...?

Comment: @alexandreiolov `lsqcurvefit` passes `vec_x` to `myfun` as the second argument.

Comment: got it, so lsqcurvefit is not like the other optimizers, which just require function with 1 argument,  but both the independent and the data points  ).

Comment: @alexandreiolov Indeed.  To quote the docs: "The `lsqcurvefit` function uses the same algorithm as `lsqnonlin`. `lsqcurvefit` simply provides a convenient interface for data-fitting problems."

Comment: Are you sure the "Curv-fit App" uses `lsqcurvefit`? This function is in the Optimization Toolbox, while the `cftool` GUI (if that's what you meant) is in the Curve Fitting Toolbox. Are you using the same starting point in the GUI? See also the difference between the default parameters (`MaxFunEvals`,`TolX`, etc.) for [`lsqcurvefit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html#inputs) and [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#input_argument_namevalue_maxfunevals).

Comment: the vector fmpd_dinosaur is the vector vec_x, i changed the name. I edited my post and i attached a snapshot of the GUI-fitting-Curve. i think the GUI uses the lsqcurvefit because i obtain the same values for the optimized values x(1) and x(2)

Comment: That image looks **just** like `cftool`. So check out my earlier comment, if it helps.

Comment: I verified. they are the same because i obtain the same optimized parameters. For plotting i'm doing like this : y=erfc((x(1)+x(2)*vec_x)/sqrt(2))/2; x(1) and x(2) are the optimized parameters obtained from the "lsqcurvefit" function. then i plot : plot(vec_x,y). the curve still not the same as the one on the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the doc of Matlab. For plotting the curve fit from the Cftool, we should select File->Generate code. The Curve Fitting app generates code from the current session and displays the file in the MATLAB Editor. The file includes all fits and plots in the current session. We have to execute the code to have the plot.

this is the code that was generated by Matlab:

```
function [fitresult, gof] = createFit_MSSI_Venus(RockerArm, mos)
%CREATEFIT1(ROCKERARM,MOS)
%  Create a fit.
%
%  Data for 'Psychometric curve fitting MSSI-RockeArm 3D mesh' fit:
%      X Input : RockerArm
%      Y Output: mos
%  Output:
%      fitresult : a fit object representing the fit.
%      gof : structure with goodness-of fit info.
%
%  See also FIT, CFIT, SFIT.

%  Auto-generated by MATLAB on 08-Jan-2016 15:40:41


%% Fit: 'Psychometric curve fitting MSSI-RockeArm 3D mesh'.
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( RockerArm, mos );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'erfc((a+b*x)/sqrt(2))/2', 'independent', 'x',  
'dependent', 'y' );

opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
opts.Algorithm = 'Levenberg-Marquardt';
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.StartPoint = [0.655477890177557 0.171186687811562];

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );

% Plot fit with data.
figure( 'Name', 'Psychometric curve fitting MSSI-RockeArm 3D mesh' );
h = plot( fitresult, xData, yData);
set(h, 'Markersize',20);
legend( h, 'mos vs. RockerArm', 'Psychometric curve fitting MSSI-        
RockeArm 3D mesh', 'Location', 'NorthEast' );

% Label axes
xlabel MSSI-RockerArm 3D mesh
ylabel mos
grid on
```

Thanks again

Comment: Is it possible that you simply mixed up `x(1)` and `x(2)`?

Comment: i added the code generated by Matlab. there is no mix

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should've added my comment to your question, since I was referring to the problem in your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640536/plot-optimized-curve-matlab/34679312?noredirect=1#comment57102777_34640536). I guess what matters that it's OK now.